# Using removeall map layers for QgsProject in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to rewrite a projekt with new layers while owerwriting all old layers. I found the function [removeAllMapLayers](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#acc2b7f20659b63aa9d4786ae9382afd0) in the qgis.core api

But when i try:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.removeAllMapLayers()
```

Where I am in a project with some layers. After trying the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsProject' object has no attribute 'removeAllMapLayers'
```

Is there any other way to empty all layer in a project? I want to write to the same project when it's empty.

Comment: It works and clears all. Unfortunatley i also want to be able to clear projects I am not in but that isn't how my question is frased.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [QgsMapLayerRegistry::removeAllMapLayers()](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html#a9d1844cbbe2bc5db119ddb97cbe10229) method to remove all layers in your project:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it through the QgsProject Class?

Comment: @VilyaSeeFour - Atleast in QGIS 2.18, `removeAllMapLayers()` no longer seems to be available in the QgsProject Class. You could use `QgsProject.instance().clear()` which resets your project to a completely blank state. Or iterate all layers in your project using a `for` loop and then remove them using `QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers()` :)

Comment: use QgsProject.instance().clear()  ,http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsProject.html#a0f169ebc035fcec0255f43e745a7cbd3 in QGIS3 you have QgsProject.instance().removeAllMapLayers () ,https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#acdb28493575b0d47d82ef9d533497042